# Laravel array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array Error

Tags: php, laravel

So, I'm new to Laravel and I'm currently following the tutorial from techdiaries (https://www.techiediaries.com/php-laravel-crud-mysql-tutorial/)

I haven't really got any experience using Laravel or any frameworks but I'm experienced in PHP and this is the first attempt at Laravel.

I'm getting the following message:

ErrorException
array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

When I view http://localhost/laravel-first-crud-app/public/

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('contacts.index', 'ContactController');
    //return 'Hello';
});

Route::resource('contacts', 'ContactController');
//Route::apiResource('contacts', 'ContactController'); //Not sure if this should be here or not
```

In routes/web.php but I couldn't see in the tutorial how to access the pages I created

Not sure if this is helpful by my contactController.php file has the following:

```
public function index()
    {
         $contacts = Contact::all();

         return view('contacts.index', compact('contacts'));
    }
```

And it's Laravel 6 with PHP7.1

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I don't know Laravel but it appears that the second arg to `view()` needs to be an array.  Notice your one line `compact('contacts')` creates an array, your other does not `'ContactController'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is this statement:

```
return view('contacts.index', 'ContactController');
```

The `view` function takes a string as the first argument and an array as the second argument for the data to pass to the view. Not sure what your intent is to pass a string of a Controller name as the data.

If there is no data to send to the view, don't use the second argument:

```
return view('contacts.index');
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Views - Passing Data to Views](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views#passing-data-to-views)

The routes from the tutorial:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('contacts', 'ContactController');
```

Comment: I had a feeling it would be that statement but I'm not that familiar with Laravel and it's syntax. I'm guessing the second argument should be an array, just not sure how to update the code to work. I didn't want to scrap the tutorial and find a different one as I was hoping that this debug process would help me to learn Laravel

Comment: remove the second argument as it isn't an array ... if there is data the view needs, you pass it via that argument, if not, don't use it

Comment: the tutorial wants the `welcome` view returned from your route and the Controller's index method handles returning your `contacts.index` view, so you can just update to match the tutorial's routes

Comment: I couldn't find the code in the tutorial so I think I've gone blind to it from starting at it for so long. Literally checked it around 6-7 times.

Comment: Thank you. With the updated code, what path would I need to access the contacts as "public/" shows me the welcome page?

Comment: "public/contacts" comes back as 404 Not Found

Comment: you shouldn't be accessing the public folder directly ... you should have the webserver configured to rewrite the url correctly, so your web server configuration is not correct

Comment: Thank you for your help and assistance. I'll double chech my server configuration to make sure that URL rewrite is on (as I'm guessing that's what's wrong here)

Comment: make sure to check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#web-server-configuration